# Is IE9 standards mode officially supported by MS with Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, internet-explorer-9

The link here says IE9 is "supported"
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526(v=office.14).aspx

Now, does that mean standards mode or just IE8 mode?

Background:
We want to deploy IE9 to get canvas support whilst not breaking anything in Sharepoint. A quick google search brings up a number of issues such as drag/drop webparts in edit mode and people picker There are fixes, but they don't appear to be MS supported. I was wondering if anyone contacted their support directly to get an official stance from them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From experience, I can say no.  We have had significant issues when trying to use, in particular, calendar controls.  They do not render correctly in IE9 Standards mode but render perfectly in IE8 Standards.

Microsoft being incompatible with Microsoft!  How (predictably) strange.

Comment: Thanks; I've now had a couple more people tell me that it's not supported.

Answer (score 1):

I use a DOCTYPE (HTML5) for my masterpage (Sharepoint 2010) and I found that IE8, IE9 and IE10 in Standard Mode could have some bad behaviors with several features that don't work anymore like the Gantt View, or editing a form when there is a "multiple line of text" field, and other stuff.

I spent several days doing reverse engineering to find the issues from the JavaScript wrote by Microsoft.

I shared the results on my blog : http://blog.kodono.info/wordpress/2013/03/20/sharepoint-2010-and-ie-in-standard-mode-issues-with-ie9ie10/ and http://blog.kodono.info/wordpress/2012/11/08/webpart-doesnt-work-with-ie8-in-standard-mode-under-sharepoint-2010/

We use Sharepoint 2010 for only 1 month so I'm pretty sure I'll find some other features that don't work in the future....